# When should we use std::unique_ptr vs std::shared_ptr for class memeber variables?

Tags: c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I know the general philosophy behind `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>`. A unique pointer should be used in cases where no other pointer variable will ask for access to the object / primitive data pointed to by the unique pointer. A shared pointer, however, exists for shared/concurrent access to a single resource such as a file.

This all remains true for class data members of pointer types as well of course. However, in particular regards at the implementation level, does this general rule cover all cases?

- Assume that you have a class with 3 member variables, all of pointer type. If none of your member functions return a pointer to one of these variables (such as a getter function) then you should declare the member variable to be of type `std::unique_ptr<T>`. If however, you return one these member variables then you could potentially have a situation where another pointer tries to bind to the same resource. In which case, you should declare that particular member to be of type `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

This seems to be a logical rule to follow. I guess, what I'm trying to figure out is how to deal with smart pointers when declared as member variables because the decision is more difficult.

Comment: IMO, this question as it is, is a bit broad. First of all you need to decide if you need smart pointers at all, or can store by value. If you really need to use pointers, it is mainly a question of ownership not primarily of access. I think there was a nice CppCon talk by Herb Sutter or Arthur O'Dwyer on that topic a few years ago.

Comment: @chtz so it's more about, which class is responsible for deleting what object, rather than who requires access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A unique pointer should be used in cases where no other pointer variable will ask for access to the object / primitive data pointed to by the unique pointer. A shared pointer, however, exists for shared/concurrent access to a single resource such as a file.

I have a different understanding. The difference between unique and shared ptr is not the access. It is the lifecycle.

unique_ptr doesn't support copy semantics so it always has a single owner.

So I think for a class member variable, it depends on whether you want the class instance to be the only owner of the lifecycle.

Another benefit of unique_ptr is that, in most cases, it has the same size as a raw ptr. So it is smaller and faster than shared_ptr.